# How can I promote an instance of a Java class to a Spring Bean when launching Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

How can I pass an instance of a Java class dynamically to a Spring configuration when I launch a Spring Boot application?

I have a `ThirdPartyService` that requires `SomeConfig` when it is instantiated. Now, I would like to wrap this service using a custom `ServiceWrapper` and then use Spring Boot to launch it programmatically without that the user of the `ServiceWrapper` is aware of that Spring Boot is used behind the scene, `ServiceWrapperTest` gives you an idea about how I intend to use it:

```java
@Service
public class ThirdPartyService {
    private final SomeConfig someConfig;

    @Autowired
    public ThirdPartyService(final SomeConfig someConfig) {
        this.someConfig = someConfig;
    }

    void start() {
        // reads values from someConfig and starts the service
    }

    void stop() {
        // stops the service
    }
}
```

```java
public class SomeConfig {
    // getters and setters omitted
}
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServiceWrapper {
    private ThirdPartyService thirdPartyService;

    public ServiceWrapper() {
    }

    public void start(SomeConfig someConfig) {
        // how can I pass someConfig to Spring Boot?
        thirdPartyService = SpringApplication.run(ThirdPartyService.class).getBean(ThirdPartyService.class);
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (thirdPartyService != null) {
            thirdPartyService.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

```java
class ServiceWrapperTest {

    @Test
    void testStartAndStop() {
        SomeConfig someConfig = new SomeConfig();
        ServiceWrapper serviceWrapper = new ServiceWrapper(someConfig);

        serviceWrapper.start();
        serviceWrapper.stop();
    }
}
```

Unsurprisingly, the test fail with following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.test.ThirdPartyService required a bean of type 'com.example.test.SomeConfig' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.test.SomeConfig' in your configuration.
```

How can I pass the `SomeConfig` instance to Spring Beot so that it becomes eligible for auto-wiring? Is it possible to use `@Bean`, `@Configuration` or similar (I don't think so)?

---

Spring Boot version 2.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `ApplicationContextInitializer` to make the existing instance of `SomeConfig` available as a bean:

```java
public void start(SomeConfig someConfig) {
    SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(ServiceWrapper.class);
    application.addInitializers(new ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>() {

        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            applicationContext.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("someConfig", someConfig);
        }
        
    });
    ThirdPartyService service = application.run().getBean(ThirdPartyService.class);
    // Use service as needed
}
```

Comment: @andy-wilksinson Thanks, I like your suggestion and I did think it would work when I read it. Regrettably, it fails with the same error message as my original example (`Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.testThirdPartyService required a bean of type 'com.example.test.SomeConfig' that could not be found.`). Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. A `static` `run` method was being called accidentally which meant that the initializer configured on the `SpringApplication` instance wasn't being used. I've corrected that now.

Comment: thanks, much appriciated

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you mean:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServiceWrapper {

    @Bean
    SomeConfig getSomeConfig() {
      return someConfig;
    }

    private static SomeConfig someConfig; // really not thread safe
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public void start(SomeConfig someConfig) {
        this.someConfig = someConfig;

        this.context = SpringApplication.run(ServiceWrapper.class);

        // do whatever you want with ThirdPartyService
        ThirdPartyService service = this.context.getBean(ThirdPartyService.class);
    }

    public void stop() {
        this.context.close();
    }
}
```

This way you make SomeConfig a bean for Spring and use that to wire your context, but you don't need to change any code in SomeConfig. You have then ThirdPartyService populated, and you can return it with a getter.

Comment: Thanks. This suggestion works, but I would like to avoid a `static` reference to `SomeConfig` if possible. Admittedly, the `getSomething()` method could pass a copy of the `SomeConfig` instance which would improve the situation somewhat, but it would still not be thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

You could annotate it with **@Component** if it is just a third-party class and do the standard constructor or field injection in the *ServiceWrapper*. Also since Spring 5.2, you don't have to explicitly annotate the dependency injection with **@Autowired**.

```
@Service
 public class ThirdPartyService {
 
    private final SomeConfig someConfig;

    public ThirdPartyService(final SomeConfig someConfig) {
        this.someConfig = someConfig;
    }

    void start() {
        // reads values from someConfig and starts the service
    }

    void stop() {
        // stops the service
    }
}

@Component
public class SomeConfig {
    // getters and setters omitted
}
```

That is if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: thanks for your response. I am aware of the `@Component` annotation, but in this case I attempt to instantiate `SomeConfig` before Spring has started and then pass it as a reference to the application context, see [Andy's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70267763/303598)